# Timeout with EvaluateExpressionAsync<>?

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I'm using Puppeteer sharp to render reports and part of that is executing user provided javascript to prepare the data for the report.

I use AddScriptTagAsync to add the scripts to the page then call the user provided script before rendering the report.

If the user provided javascript has an issue that causes an infinite loop (for example) then my call to `EvaluateExpressionAsync` could await forever:

`await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<dynamic>($"Prepare({DataObject});")`

I can't pass a cancellation token to `EvaluateExpressionAsync` so I can't control it and there appear to be no timeouts available for this method.

I would like to limit it to a controllable number of seconds and then have it timeout.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [WaitForExpressionAsync](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_WaitForExpressionAsync_System_String_PuppeteerSharp_WaitForFunctionOptions_).
The idea of this method is executing the expression over a period of time until the result is truthy.
But if you make sure that your expression will always return a truthy value, WaitForExpressionAsync will timeout using the timeout you pass as an option.

Comment: Thank you, hmmm...that's what I guessed originally however passing the exact same expression to WaitForExpressionAsync errors out where it runs fine with EvaluteExpressionAsync and I never had any luck with it.  I expected it to just accept the same expression and work the same but with a timeout and then after reading the docs it seemed like it maybe worked differently.  I'll have a look at that again, thank you.

Comment: Should have mentioned the error is ""Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'\n    at new Function (<anonymous>)\n    at waitForPredicatePageFunction (__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:21)"" with the exact same function call to processes without error with EvaluateExpressionAsync and when I read the examples they seemed to show waiting on DOM elements rather than a script.  I'll dig into it again but there is some kind of difference between WaitforExpressionAsync and EvaluateExpressionAsync in what it expects.

Comment: Wait for expression is documented as "Waits for an expression to be evaluated to a truthy value" and EvaluateExpressionAsync is documented as "Executes a script in browser context".  I'll dig into the source code next but it doesn't seem like one is a substitute for the other?

Comment: It doesn't substitute but it should do the job.

Comment: Ah...ok, I see what I'm doing wrong.  It needs to call the function as part of an expression, not call the function directly this change works: await page.WaitForExpressionAsync($"Prepare({DataObject})!=null", w);  Thank you @hardkoded!